# MVC 4 Controller Compilation Error trying to return a Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a newbie configuration problem I suspect.

See return statement comment in code snippet.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TestService()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "DataLayer Service";

        Service dataLayerService = new Service {CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()};
        dataLayerService.SetSessionAppName("SAND");
        WebServiceModel webServiceModel = new WebServiceModel();            
        webServiceModel.Result = dataLayerService.GetSessionAppName();

        return this.View(webServiceModel); // <== Cannot resolve View "TestService"            
    }
```

Comment: Well do you have a view called "TestService"? It would be in Views/(ControllerName)/

Comment: Okay, solved my problem.  I needed to create a strongly typed view. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a view called "TestService" that take for parameter a WebServiceModel?

Your web project must contain in the **Views** folder a folder with the name of the controller and a file called TestService.cshtml.

This file should have in its header

```
@model WebServiceModel
```

If you want to be able to use it in the view.